# Extra spaces when creating field with VBA:  { EQ... } instead of {EQ...}

Tags: vba, ms-word, field

I use VBA to create an overlapping character in Word:

```
a = "x"
b = "."
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:= _
        "EQ \o (" & a & "," & b & ")", PreserveFormatting:=False
```

The output is

```
{ EQ \o (x,.) }
```

which produces: http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/3783/18492133.png. As can be seen by the gray box, the character is to wide. The width can be reduced to http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/1723/69344761.png by changing the field manually to

```
{ EQ \o (x,.)}    or   {EQ \o (x,.)}
```

But how can this be achieved directly in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is you need to remove the trailing space between the final paranthesis and curly bracket.

Dim x As String

Dim y As String

x = "{ EQ \o (x,.) }"

y = Replace(x, " }", "}") 'Note the space for the find expression e.g. ' }'
'Could also put ") }" replace with ")}"

y becomes the output I think you desire

You can just use the replace function shown above to accomplish this task.

Your code would become

```
a = "x"
b = "."
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:= _
"EQ \o (" & a & "," & b & ")", PreserveFormatting:=False
Selection.Range.Text = Replace(Selection.Range.Text, ") }", ")}")
```

Comment: Could you post an example as to how to create a field based on `y`?

Comment: Please find revised answer. Just put the method into your original example.

Comment: Thanks for the revision. However, it does not seem work for me. I would think that Replace() is executed before Selection.Fields.Add(), and there is no ") }" in the string to replace...

Comment: Great point, if we have any way after that Fields.Add method to refer back to what it wrote, we could call the replace method there. This would emulate you doing the same manually. I took a shot at it above.

Answer (score 0):

This code assign correct value to field EQ

```
 ActiveDocument.Fields.Item(numderfield).Code.Text = "EQ \o (" & a & "," & b & ")"
```